# Check if specific shipping method is enabled on WooCommerce cart page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, shipping-method

In WooCommerce cart page I am using the code below to check if specific shipping method is enabled, but the condition on the if statement is always true, so it doesn't work.

```
    global $woocommerce;
    $shipping_methods = $woocommerce->shipping->load_shipping_methods();
    if ( $shipping_methods['free_shipping']->enabled == "yes" ) {

    }
```

How can I Check on cart page if specific shipping method is enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `enabled()` will be **yes** if the "free_shipping"  shipping method is enabled in WooCommerce shipping settings for the current shipping zone, that's why you always get "yes"…

To check that for `WC_Cart` object, you will use instead `WC_Session` related data. Here is an example for "Free shipping" shipping method:

```
// Get available shipping methods
$shipping_for_package_0 = WC()->session->get('shipping_for_package_0');
$found = false;

if( isset($shipping_for_package_0['rates']) && ! empty($shipping_for_package_0['rates']) ) {
    // Loop through available shipping methods rate data
    foreach( $shipping_for_package_0['rates'] as $rate ) {
        // Targeting "Free Shipping"
        if( 'free_shipping' === $rate->method_id ) {
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}

// Display availability for "Free shipping"
echo $found ? 'Free shipping is available.' : 'Free shipping is not available.';
```

But it will not get refreshed on cart page if the customer make changes on cart page.